# If $n$ can be expressed as $2x^2+3y^2$ with integers $x$ and $y$, then so can $7n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

The problem is:

> Let us say that a positive integer $n$ is *obtainable* if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $n=2x^2+3y^2$. If $n$ is obtainable, prove that $7n$ is also obtainable.

I tried doing that
$$2(x+a)^2+3(y+b)^2=14x^2+21y^2$$
which simplifies to
$$4ax+2a^2+6yb+3b^2=12x^2+18y^2$$
but then I seem to be caught in a loop.

Am I on the right direction and can someone give me a hint?

This is a homework question btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would modify your substitution to avoid linear term.
$$2(x+ay)^2 + 3(y+bx)^2 = 14x^2+21y^2$$

$$2(x^2+2axy+a^2y^2)+3(y^2+2bxy+b^2x^2)=14x^2+21y^2$$

$$(2+3b^2)x^2 +(4a+6b)xy + (2a^2+3)y^2=14x^2+21y^2$$

Can we find $(a,b)$ such that the equality holds for all $x,y$? I will leave the investigation to you.

Comment: this is ordinary Gauss composition for the forms $u^2 + 6 v^2$  and $2x^2 + 3 y^2,$   at the end use $u=1, v= \pm 1$

Comment: The same proof works for $6t^2+1$ instead of $7$. Just take $a=3t$ and $b=-2t$. Thanks to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2B3b%5E2%29%3D+2+k%2C+%284a%2B6b%29%3D0%2C+%282a%5E2%2B3%29%3D3+k).

Answer (score 13):

Just use this
$$7n = 2(x+3y)^2 +3 (2x-y)^2$$